# Windows Terminal - Start a new tab using the cli and run a command with fish

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-terminal, fish

I am using the wt.exe CLI to run some WSL commands in a new tab. However, I seem to be getting some weird error when using Fish shell.

The command:

```sh
wt.exe --window 0 new-tab -p Ubuntu /usr/bin/fish -C "cd /"
```

This starts a new tab but it has the following error:

```
[error 2147942402 (0x80070002) when launching `"cd /"']
```

I know I can use the `-d` flag to set the starting directory, but the `cd /` is just a placeholder command for the example, the actual command would be different.

Comment: Do you have a Windows Terminal profile configured to use the Fish shell? The error is essentially a “file not found” error. Your path wouldn’t exist or be accessible from Windows which is probably the reason the file cannot be found.

Comment: Yes I do, I have a Ubuntu profile that has fish as the default shell

Comment: So provide the formatted json for the profile.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you'll want:

```
wt.exe --window 0 new-tab -p Ubuntu -- wsl.exe -d Ubuntu /usr/bin/fish -C "cd /"
```

When you pass `-p Ubuntu`, that tells the Terminal to use your `Ubuntu` profile. However, the commandline that follows that doesn't get *appended* to "Ubuntu"'s commandline, it *replaces* it. So you need to manually pass the `wsl.exe -d Ubuntu` from the Ubuntu profile's commandline.

---

*Addendum*: I'm honestly curious that the error message isn't `` error 2147942402 (0x80070002) when launching `"/usr/bin/fish"' ``.